# htcaccess and symfony 2 redirect non www -> www

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, redirect

I have small problem.

I create redirect for my domain from non-www to www.
Anything work fine but after redirect I got index file ( app.php ) and i don't know why.

My htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex app.php    
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For example, 
If I type www.example.com -> it's ok
If I type example.com -> redirect www.example.com/app.php

How Can I remove app.php?

Comment: Are there more rules in your .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in your htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^app\.php$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
```

after

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi, that work, but now I have problem with subdomains.

Comment: how's your main domain and subdomains look alike, send some example URLs of your subdomains and main domain

Comment: another good solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43862282/symfony2-redirect-from-non-www-to-www)