# Symfony2 - Redirect from non-www to www

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, redirect, symfony-2.8

I need to redirect my symfony website from "abc.com" to "www.abc.com". I have tried some solutions in stack overflow but they add multiple "www." to the address and others didn't work.

Here is my htaccess source.

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htcaccess and symfony 2 redirect non www -> www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27398989/htcaccess-and-symfony-2-redirect-non-www-www)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following rule as the first rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\.
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```